# « Certes » : suppression du « s » pour la rime en poésie ?

Tags: orthographe, adverbes, poésie

Au TLFi à l'entrée [*certes*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/certes) (l'affirmation ou la concession ; aussi [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/certes/14297?q=certes#14152), [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/certes)) on mentionne entre autres :

> **Rem.** Les dictionnaires signalent que l'*s* final peut être supprimé par licence
>   poétique. Cela est confirmé par l'examen des occurrences de *certe* dans le
>   fonds littér. TLF. Sur 64 occurrences, 60 se trouvent dans des œuvres
>   poétiques, notamment chez A. Chénier (6 occurr.), T. Gautier (*Albertus*, 3
>   occurr.), V. Hugo (27 occurr.), Ch.-M. Leconte de Lisle (7 occurr.),
>   L. Dierx (4 occurr.), J. Moréas (3 occurr.) R. Ponchon (3 occurr.).

Au LBU14 (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>) on explique que ce *s* est directement relié à l'étymologie de *certes* (du lat. vulg. *certas*), contrairement à d'autres cas où on l'a ajouté au Moyen Âge pour marquer l'adverbe (tandis, sans, volontiers, lors etc.), d'où le terme « s adverbial », et qu'en poésie on supprime parfois le *s* de *certes* pour la **rime** ou le **mètre** (§960). Le mètre, par exemple ici l'*alexandrin* (présenté au §44) :

> Je te regarde, et tous les jours je te découvre,
>  Tant est intime
>   ou ta douceur ou ta fierté :
>  Le temps, *certe*, obscurcit les yeux
>   de ta beauté.
>
> Mais exalte ton coeur dont le fond d'or s'entre'ouvre.
>
> [ E. Verhaeren, [*Heures d'après-midi*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2138032/f95.image), XIV, extrait ]

---

Pourrait-on svp. produire un exemple précis d'un tel auteur, où l'on supprime le *s* pour faire une **rime** (par opposition au mètre, au nombre de syllabes) alors qu'on prononce le mot [sε ʀt], et expliquer ?

Comment: Une élision pour créer une rime dans de la poésie en vers (contrairement à la prose) doit être très rare, voir inexistante, car il est d'usage de marquer une pause à la fin de chaque vers pour marquer la rime (et ainsi mieux en profiter). Si on marque une pause, on perd donc l'utilité de la liaison. Et concernant la poésie en prose, je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de rime, mais je ne suis pas expert de ce type de poésie...

Comment: Ce doit être plus utile avec des rimes brisées, ou d'autre types de rime qui ne se trouvent pas en fin de vers, mais je n'ai malheureusement aucun exemple à donner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En fait c'est un peu un piège car au *LBU* on donne Rostand, *Aiglon* [I,1](https://archive.org/stream/laiglondrameensi00rostuoft#page/6/mode/2up/search/certe) et [I,9](https://archive.org/stream/laiglondrameensi00rostuoft#page/36/mode/2up/search/certe) et en vérifiant on a ces dialogues :

> — Oui, ce fut une bien grande **perte** !
>  On a trop peu connu cette
>   belle âme !
>  — Oh ! **Certe** !
>
> ---
>
> — [...] Ah ! au fait, de quel drap ?... uni tout simple !...
>  —
>   **Certe !**
>  — Et la couleur, voyons, que diriez-vous de **verte** ?

Et ainsi on s'aperçoit que ça n'a rien à voir avec la prononciation et que c'est uniquement une richesse (ortho)*graphique* qui est ajoutée à la rime. Tel qu'on mentionne en commentaire, il y a peut-être d'autres cas où c'est la prononciation qui est plus directement affectée, avec l'élision, un peu comme en question mais dans le contexte de la rime...

Comment: Il y a sans doute d'autres exemples, que j'aurais aimé dénicher...